# Roll the dice until you get 6

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, dice

I am supposed to write code that will roll dice and loop it automatically until it results 6 and then stop. My code only rolls once and repeats it endlessly.

````
import random
min=1
max=6
r=(random.randint(min, max))

while r < 6:
     print(r)
     continue
     if r == 6:
          print(r)
          break```
````

Comment: You calculate `r` once before entering your loop. Instead you want to calculate `r` on every iteration of your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate the random number at each iteration as follows:

```
import random
min_=1
max_=6

while True:
     r = random.randint(min_, max_)
     print(r)
     if r == 6:
          print(r)
          break
```

Comment: dont name variables like inbuilt functions

Answer (score 4):

You have to roll the dice **again** (aka inside the loop):

```
import random

mi, ma = 1, 6  # do not shadow built-ins `min` and `max`

while True:
    r = random.randint(mi, ma)
    print(r)
    if r == 6:
        break
```

Or with an assignment expression (using the walrus operator):

```
while (r := random.randint(mi, ma)) != 6:
    print(r)
# print(r)  # if you need to see the final 6
```